# Take a look inside a public room (bar, restaurant, museum etc) in german - Phrase

Tags: phrase

There are many times where you want to *take a look* inside some premises like a bar. Almost every day I face the following difficulty.

> How do you say (when somebody comes to speak to you and ask you for
> example if you need a table) in German: I only want to take a look and
> I will decide later. Or totally casually just say: Hey I 'll take a
> look first.

Are the 2 (following) sentences that I use correct? Die klingen, glaube ich, schief.

```
 - Ich werfe nur einen Blick.
 - Ich schaue mir rum.
```

Comment: You're never going to have a good drink if you're sightseeing only ;)

Comment: I know, one is not supposed to answer in a comment on this platform, but this is too short for an answer: *Ich schaue nur*. Both of your sentences are not good. *Ich schaue mich (nur) um* is good, also

Comment: it's not clear to me why this is labeled 'etymology'. *take* is a Norse borrowing without cognates in German. It seems to align with *ziehen* in some phrases, and *herumziehen* (to loiter; go around) should work in reference to bar evenings, but nothing in relation to viewing comes to mind.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler There's no need to write 500 words. Just explain what's wrong with OP's sentences. Then your comment is a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct phrases for the situation you describe are:

```
Ich schaue mich nur um.
Ich schaue mich erst einmal um.
```

The phrase:

```
Ich werfe nur einen Blick hinein.
```

is also correct German but implies that you're standing outside and peeking in, while the former are a better match for the situation you describe where you are inside already but trying to decide whether you'll stay.

Answer (score 2):

The verbiage would be most likely verbal, *gucken, schauen, nachsehen*. *Einen Blick werfen* for a denominal construction is common indeed and matches your starting point with *to take* best, maybe *einen Eindruck gewinnen* "get an impression" works as well in ightly elevated speech, but the prepositions are decisive. You do not just *turn an eye* but need to say *rein, heinein, in das Lokal, auf die Statue* or something of that sort. In this view, the verbal phrases match your request much better: *Ich möchte nur mal eben gucken*.

"* Ich schaue mir rum" is unacceptable. Either it's accusative *mich*, or substandard Berliner *mir* where *schauen* would be rather uncommon. As the separable verbs are *sich umschauen* or *sich umgucken*, it would never be *rum*. Without the self-reflexive there is *rumkucken*, not "* (he)rum gucken", as far as I can tell.